# Number of distinct prime power factors of Totient Numbers

Tags: number-theory

If $n>2$ is the product of $k$ distinct odd prime divisors, does $\varphi(n)$ have at least $k$ distinct prime divisors? This seems true and easy to prove but I have no idea how to prove it. Any better lower bounds? (other than that if $n$ is a Mersenne prime then $\varphi(n)$ has only 1 prime divisor)

In general what can be said about the number of distinct prime divisors of $\varphi(n)$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ (perpaps with respect to the number of distinct prime divisors of $n$)?

---

I definitely misfired. What I actually meant is the number of "distinct prime power factors" of $\varphi(n)$ in the following sense:

Statement: Let $n = p_1 \dots p_k$ where $p_i, 1 \leq i \leq k$ are distinct odd primes.
Let $q_j, 1 \leq j \leq r$ be the distinct prime divisors of $\varphi(n)$.
Let $A_j = \{ q_j^a > 1 \mid q_j^a = (p_i - 1)_{q_j} \text{if for some } 1 \leq i \leq k \}$ (here $(p_i - 1)_{q_j}$ is the $q_j$-part of $p_i - 1$), and $a_j = |A_j|$. Then $\sum_{i = 1}^r a_j \geq k$.

I'm also interested in knowing whether a slightly weaker statement is true or false: under the above assumptions, there exists $a \in \mathbb{N}, 1 \leq i \leq k, 1 \leq j \leq r$ such that $k \leq q_j^a \mid (p_i - 1)$.

---

The above statement seems incorrect with the following example: $n = 3 \times 7 \times 11 \times 23 \times 31 \times 67 \times 331$, then $k = 7$, but $r = 4$ with $2,3,5,11$ being the only prime divisors of $\varphi(n)$, and $\sum_{i = 1}^r a_j = 1+1+1+1 = 4 < k = 7$. However the weaker statement does hold in this case as $11 > 7$.

Comment: Why do you think it's "true and easy to prove "?

Comment: Nor is it true that, if $n$ is a Mersenne prime, then $\varphi(n)$ has only $1$ prime divisor. $31$ is a Mersenne Prime, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

This is clearly false. Let $n=2\cdot 3\cdot 5$. Then
$$
\phi(n)=\phi(2)\cdot \phi(3)\cdot \phi(5)=1\cdot 2\cdot 4=8=2^3.
$$
We also can achieve
$$
\phi(2\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 17)=2^7.
$$
Can you continue?

Comment: $n=6$ gives an even smaller counterexample.

Comment: Yes, this is true. I wanted to show an extremer case, i.e., a higher power of $2$, to see how badly the "distinct prime factors" can fail.

Comment: My apologies. I edited the post to reflect what I really want to ask. I am aware of the example of product of Mersenne primes, but thanks for pointing out the misstatement.

Comment: No need to apologize. It is not easy in general to compare the number of different prime divisors of $n$ and $\phi(n)$.